# How can I control the default save location for PDFs in Microsoft Word for Mac?

Tags: finder, ms-office, pdf

In Microsoft Word for Mac 2011, I often need to save a copy of a document as a PDF. To do this, I open the print dialog, and then choose "Save as PDF" from the dropdown menu at the bottom:

[image: Save as PDF]

However, this seems to, by default, open the last location I've saved a PDF in. It would be far preferable for it to default to the location of the .docx file I'm working with. Is there a way to achieve this result?

Comment: Default directories for both open (GetFile) and save (PutFile) are defined in the com.microsoft.word.plist file in the ~/Library/Preferences folder. However, the value is not tied to your working directory, but the last value invoked by the user (i.e., the last place you opened or saved a document).

Comment: So in theory, it should default to the location of the .docx file, if I had just saved that file, correct? Unfortunately, that's not the behavior I observe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The save as PDF option in the Print window is controlled by the system, not Word. It will default to the last place you saved a PDF because that's all it knows about. It is completely separate from (and unaware of) the Open and Save dialog boxes. That said, you can save a Word document as a PDF from File > Save As, and that will respect your last working directory related to the docx file.